# How can I scan devices connected on my second router but with different ip addresses

Tags: networking, router, lan, home-networking, dhcp

[My simplified network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCnSn.png)

My ISP-issued router has a DHCP service enabled serving ip address in range of 192.168.1.1-255

My second router, Mercusys also have a DHCP service giving ip address in range of 192.168.2.100-200

I tried to disable the DHCP service on my 2nd router but my primary router doesn't assign ip addresses connected to my 2nd router. Leaving my with no option other than having a second DHCP server on my 2nd router

My router is Mercusys MW301R

Edit: I also wanna scan the open ports on the devices connected on 2nd router

Comment: What prevents you from doing it?

Comment: My laptop cannot ping devices on the second router, and also unreachable

Comment: You need to create a route to those devices. No route, no scanning. The ISP router must contain a route to the Mercusys router, and your PC declares the ISP router either as the default router or as the router to the network on the other side of the Mercusys.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help, I appreciate it man.